# Best way to re-initialize WordPress mediaelement after ajax load?

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

I have a WordPress site in which videos work great with mediaelement.js

However, part of the functionality of my site includes ajax loading new video elements on a page. By default, it makes sense that they don't get impacted by the mediaelement.js script.

After the ajax load I can do the following:
`jQuery('video').mediaelementplayer();`

It works, but doesn't pick up on the custom settings I have hooked into for mediaelement in WordPress (such as adding download functionality to the player). So I need to use the functionality I set up with the included mediaelement.js/

How would I do this using the exisiting file? I've tried to reference the wpMediaElement() function or initialize, but I can't seem to call it correctly (syntax errors or function missing errors).